# UICollectionView Crashes on iOS 6.0 on iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, ios6, iphone-3gs

The app supposedly crashes while displaying the UICollectionView. It creates a low memory crash log as well. How can I reduce the memory usage in UICollectionView? I am using ARC in the project. Please help...(P.S. below is my code)

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [untaggedImagesArray count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    @autoreleasepool {

    static NSString *identifier = @"imageCell";
    imageCell *cvc = (imageCell *)[self.iamgesCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cvc == nil){
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"imageCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass: [imageCell class]]){
                cvc = (imageCell*)currentObject;


                break;
            }
        }
    }
    NSString *path = [untaggedImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSString *path = [untaggedImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getImage:) withObject:path];

    UIImage *cache_image = [images_cache objectForKey:path];

    if(cache_image)
    {
        [cvc.imageView setImage:cache_image];
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getImage:) withObject:path];
        //UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [images_cache setObject:cellImage forKey:path];
         [cvc.imageView setImage:cellImage];
    }


    if([preTaggedPaths containsObject:path]){
        [cvc.tagLabel setText:[tagStringsDict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]]];
        [cvc setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }else{
        [cvc.tagLabel setText:@""];
        [cvc setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }

        if([selectedImagesPath containsObject:path]){
            [cvc.checkImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_small_selected.png"]];
        }else{
            [cvc.checkImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_small_unselected.png"]];
        }

//
    return cvc;
    }
}



-(void)getImage:(NSString*)path{
    cellImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"clicked to select at index%d",indexPath.row);
    imageCell *cvc = (imageCell*)[self.iamgesCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *pathString = [untaggedImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cvc.checkImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_small_selected.png"]];
    [selectedImagesPath addObject:pathString];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     NSLog(@"clicked to DEselect at index%d",indexPath.row);
    imageCell *cvc = (imageCell*)[self.iamgesCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *pathString = [untaggedImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cvc.checkImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_small_unselected.png"]];
    [selectedImagesPath removeObject:pathString];
//    [cvc setSelected:NO];
}
```

-

```
(void)getImage:(NSString*)path{
    //cellImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"image path: %@", path);
    cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:path];

}
```

Comment: try changing the getImage: method to load the images with "[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];" and tell me if it stops crashing.

Answer (score 3):

Your are saying that the crash is caused by low memory!

A possible problem is your image loading mechanism (What's the size of your images?):

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

This will be executed every time for each cell in your collection view.

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"name"];
```

for example is caching the image, whereas imageWithContentsOfFile does not!

So UIImage's methods `imageNamed:` and `imageWithContentsOfFile` do slightly different things. `imageNamed` loads the image in a special system cache, and then future calls with that image path will return the image in the cache instead of reloading it from disk. `imageWithContentsOfFile` simply loads the image at the path you specify, but does no caching. Multiple calls to `imageWithContentsOfFile` for the same image will result in multiple copies in memory.

If this is your problem, try caching the images or use a smart way to only load images which are being displayed at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @alex for your suggession .. should i resize (create thumnails ) images.

Comment: There are many ways to prevent the app from crashing due to memory overload. Like I said in my answer, I would try to load only the images which are really being displayed on screen. Further try cache the images for ur self (e.g. NSCache)

Comment: i have applied cache but still its not working after 8 images .. i ahve edited my question with caching of images.

Comment: Have you tried to use instruments to track your memory usage and find the lead? Whats the size of your images? If u are loading 50 images of 1 MB each it should be clear that this doesn't work... Then try loading only the images your are really displaying